# Android Studio - Emulator not running

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am getting the error "the emulator process for avd was killed" and I have researched questions on this side with similar issues and tried things like reinstalling haxm and running a fresh install of android studio.

Here are the logs, please can someone educate me I'm so frustrated

```
2020-10-16 17:08:00,561 [   1348]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2020-10-16 17:08:00,628 [   1415]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk] 
2020-10-16 17:08:00,648 [   1435]   WARN - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Extension to be removed not found: class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.test.runner.TestClassGradleConfigurationProducer 
2020-10-16 17:08:00,762 [   1549]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.symbols.DebugSymbolNotifications) 
2020-10-16 17:08:01,200 [   1987]   INFO - rd.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider - Overriding welcome frame to be resizable 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,410 [   7197]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\Cian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,427 [   7214]   INFO - roid.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: C:\Users\Cian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,439 [   7226]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_4], use -list-avds to see valid list. 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,439 [   7226]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel_4.ini in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,439 [   7226]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd and $HOME\.android\avd) 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,440 [   7227]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1 
2020-10-16 17:08:06,441 [   7228]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 1 
2020-10-16 17:08:08,508 [   9295]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 
2020-10-16 17:08:08,529 [   9316]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully 
2020-10-16 17:08:08,537 [   9324]   INFO -            #com.android.ddmlib - Connected to adb for device monitoring 
2020-10-16 17:08:08,736 [   9523]   INFO - roid.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Successfully connected to adb
```

Edited Logs

```
2020-10-16 18:12:02,605 [ 881852]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\Cian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_XL_API_30 
2020-10-16 18:12:02,631 [ 881878]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_4_XL_API_30], use -list-avds to see valid list. 
2020-10-16 18:12:02,631 [ 881878]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel_4_XL_API_30.ini in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd 
2020-10-16 18:12:02,631 [ 881878]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd and $HOME\.android\avd) 
2020-10-16 18:12:02,631 [ 881878]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1 
2020-10-16 18:12:02,631 [ 881878]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 1 
2020-10-16 18:12:32,480 [ 911727]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\Cian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_XL_API_30 
2020-10-16 18:12:32,506 [ 911753]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_4_XL_API_30], use -list-avds to see valid list. 
2020-10-16 18:12:32,506 [ 911753]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel_4_XL_API_30.ini in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd 
2020-10-16 18:12:32,506 [ 911753]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd and $HOME\.android\avd) 
2020-10-16 18:12:32,506 [ 911753]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1 
2020-10-16 18:12:32,506 [ 911753]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel_4.ini in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd`

it seems you have configured an emulator without an image or the image might have been delted later.

all you have to do is download a valid emulator image and then reconfigure emulator and after that you can expect things to work properly

[EDIT]: based on update in question

there are two important messages in log

- `Unknown AVD name [Pixel_4_XL_API_30], use -list-avds to see valid list`
- `ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel_4_XL_API_30.ini in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd`

in the first error it seems the the emunlator is not running so the error is about that

in second error there might be some path mismatch due to which the image is not found by the emulator before running.

so you check manually at path `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd` do you see your emulator images ? then comment back

Comment: Do I do that in android studio?

Comment: yes when selecting emulator or device from menun in android studio just click on add new emulator or something of this sort option and create an emulator from scratch. make sure you have downloaed a proper image

Comment: I downloaded a different image and that doesn't work either.

Comment: images are about 1GB in size. are you sure you downloaded a new image ? post the new error log you get

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: In the avd folder I see:

`
Folder: Nexus_6_API_29.avd
Folder: Pixel_3.avd
File: Nexus_6_API_29.ini
File: Pixel_3.ini
`

Comment: @BranOIE the demanded images are `Pixel_4_XL_API_30.ini` and `Pixel_4.ini` and they dont exists so downloaded any of the images and run those emulators

Comment: I give up. Do I have to have evironmental variables that maybe I'm missing?

Comment: everything is fine only the files are missing

Comment: They arent I can see them. I think the path is the issue

Comment: check the value of `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` in your project configuration

Comment: I got it working, I deleted completely any relevant environmental variables and that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by following instructions on Github https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows#Installing_Intel_HAXM_on_Windows_via_Android_Studio

setting the user variables
ANDROID_SDK_HOME to C:\users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
then in a command prompt,
launching %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools\emulator –avd <avd_name> -verbose –show-kernel
the result shows the three names for the environment variable relating to AVD,
I then added ANDROID_AVD_HOME pointing to  C:\users\myusername\ .android\avd

Answer (score -1):

On my machine I had only 2GB of free disk space. Once I freed up some disk space up to ~10GB the emulator started ok.